# Need to check if user selected only me to share [facebook api]

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to figure out how can I get to know if a user shares a link to his feed selecting only me as an option. I want to know this because if the user shares my link to himself then the promotion of my website won't be possible.

```
<div id="fb-share">Share</div>
<div class="social-share-wrap"></div>
jQuery('#fb-share').on('click', function() {
        checkLoginState();
    });

    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            shareUrl();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            checkLoginState();
        } else {
            checkLoginState();
        }
    };

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        }, {scope: 'email'});
    };

function shareUrl() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'http://www.example.com',
        }, function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    jQuery.post('test.php',{name: response.name, email: response.email}).done(function(data) {
                        jQuery('.social-share-wrap').html(data);
                        jQuery.fancybox({
                            href: '#social-share',
                            centerOnScroll: true,
                            hideOnOverlayClick: false
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            } else {
                console.log('cancelled by user');
            }
        });
    };
```

In the above code what I'm doing is when a user clicks the share div the user gets the login popup and then the user gets the permission popup and then the share iframe appears now if the user shares successfully his info is posted to test.php and if the user cancels it gets logged in console. I did not find anything in the api where I can get to know if user selects custom and sets it to only me.

Comment: Your case is my case. I am making a game, if users play with share button then they will get a coin, but if they let the permission to share is 'Only Me', they will get many coins (that make cheat my game), so I wonder know what exactly way to detect the permission when they sharing, anybody can help me?

Comment: Hi @fahad.kazi Did you get the answer for the above question, if yes please share to me

Comment: @shivashankarm the answer is already the accepted one. Facebook does not give you the option to detect it. As this is upto the user. Can't do much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t check the permission setting, it´s completely up to the user and there is no way to detect which one he selected. After all, you are not allowed to incentivize sharing according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), so it´s not really relevant to know.

Comment: The thing is I'm generating a discount code for promotional purpose. So when somebody clicks on share the coupon code is generated. And that is why this question came up. I am surprised my question got down voted.

Comment: exactly, that´s not allowed, you can´t reward users for sharing in any way. not sure why the question got downvoted though, it´s not a bad question at all...